# Laravel global send to address for testing

Tags: email, laravel, swiftmailer

I know how to set a global 'from' address in Laravel's mailer but I need to set a global 'to' address.

I want to see the output of the emails but not send them to the actual user just yet.

Swiftmailer has a delivery_address setting which does this but I can't seem to find this in Laravel's config.

Comment: Laravel has an option to fake email sending, saving them to the log instead. That might be more helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I've already used the pretend feature, I know want to see the actual email output :)

Comment: There's no way to set a global `to` address without modifying the Laravel core. You could, however, define a new config item to store the address, and then set the `to` field for each email to that config item. At least that way you won't have litter your code with a temporary email address.

Comment: Cheers, I've created a function to swap the address for a default config setting depending on the environment.

I really thought there'd be a way to hook into the swiftmailer somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but maybe it's still relevant to someone.

Instead of returning the config array in `config/mail.php` you could define the global TO address depending on the App Environment:

```
$config = [
// ... default laravel configuration ...
];

// global TO Address for all sent mails
if (env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS') && env('APP_ENV') !== 'production') {
    $config['to'] = [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME', 'Example'),
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Now you can define `MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=globalto@address.com` in your .env file, which will only take effect when the environment is not in production.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#mail-and-local-development).

Set the pretend option in the config/mail.php configuration file to true. Your mails will be written to your log files.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done this, but now I need to see the output of the actual emails. I thought it would be simple to define a global send address while in development.

Comment: I'm afraid theres no easy option for that. Either hardcode you email address in the code instead of the desired one or Laravel suggest using [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this in Laravel documentation: [Using a global `to` address in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#using-a-global-to-address). It exists since version 8.